# multi-condition php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I wrote a simple script with many conditions:

```
$item =12;
    if($item < 5)
    { 
    //display icon buyer
    }
    elseif ($item < 10)
    {
    //display icon buyer
    }
    elseif ($item < 15)
    {
    //display icon good buyer
    }
    elseif ($item < 20)
    {
    //display icon top buyer
    }
    // etc....
```

It's a long multi condition and I know is very bad.

How I could optimize the code?

**Note.** `switch` is not possible because I'm using the operators `<` and  `>`, etc.

Comment: who told you, that you can't use `<>` with the switch statement?

Comment: You can definitely use `switch`, (`switch (true)`, `case ($item<15)`).  I'd say it's probably fine either way.

Comment: I would go as far as to say I would prefer a `switch` statements over multiple `if-elses` anyday of the week.

Comment: I thought just thats switch testing equality... so thank you

Comment: @Kate, you are right, it does test only equality, the suggested solution by Brad tests whether true == true, by evaluating the boolean value of an expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better than a bunch of conditionals is to look for a pattern that allows to just calculate it.

In your case it looks like that are steps by 5 - so appropriate for division.

---

Or map it:

```
$item = 12;

$icons = [
    10 => 'buyer',
    15 => 'good buyer',
    20 => 'top buyer',
];

foreach ($icons as $value => $icon) {
    if ($item < $value) {
        return $icon;
    }
}
return null;
```

Which allows more flexible steps (as you have it in your data in question).

Comment: interesting approach with foreach and It's easy for futur maintenance.

Answer (score 9):

Give this a go ([**demo**](http://codepad.org/yXzKJ2Rb)):

```
<?php
function icon($item) {
    $icons = array(
        'buyer',
        'buyer',
        'good buyer',
        'top buyer'
    );
    $index = max(0, min(3, $item / 5));
    return $icons[$index];
}

$item = 12;
echo icon($item) . "\n";

$item = 1;
echo icon($item) . "\n";

$item = 100;
echo icon($item) . "\n";
```

---

Simply add to the `$icons` array for more options / icons.

Comment: Wow, it's a very good solution so thank you and merry christmas for all :-)

Comment: As integer are "floorly" in PHP, checkout the `min` and `max` functions for some nice mice: `$index = max(0, min(count($icons), $item / 5)); return $icons[$index];`

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff Brilliant.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: Because you know how many elements there are in already, you can store the count (like the array) into a variable, too. - or just write in the magic number. I hope you're not disturbed by the edits :~

Comment: @hakre I used `count($icons)` so that it would be easier to update the list: the list isn't this short, it's longer. IMO, it's better to get PHP to count the list instead of having to count a (possibly long) list manually :-) BTW, I would prefer it if you commented first, rather than just editing my code.

Comment: Are you sure trading in readability for micro-optimization is the right thing to do here?

Comment: @lesderid Can you clarify?

Comment: His original code is quite a bit easier to understand than your code. I'm not saying it's bad as it's obviously shorter, which is why I didn't downvote. I'm just saying that I *personally* would keep the original code.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting, with no irony whatsoever, that a set of if/elseif is *easier to understand* than a small, self-contained function that does the same thing in a tenth of the lines?